# Can't get a value string from post input - mod wsgi

Tags: python, apache, post, html-parsing, mod-wsgi

I'm out of ideas why I can't save to file a value (string) from html input using Apache24, mod wsgi and following (Python 3.6.5) code:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
import urllib.parse

def application(environ, start_response):

    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    f = open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'Wsgi_Apache.html'))
    output = f.read().encode('utf-8').strip()
    f.close()

    try:
        request_body_size = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH', 0))
    except (ValueError):
        request_body_size = 0

    request_body = environ['wsgi.input'].read(request_body_size)
    d = urllib.parse.parse_qs(request_body)
    #d = urllib.parse.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])

    download = d.get('download', [''])[0]
    file = open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'down.txt'), 'w')
    file.write(download)
    file.close()

    status = '200 OK'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html;charset=UTF-8'),
                    ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

And HTML code (Wsgi_Apache.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><body>
<form method="post" action="">
<input id="download" type="hidden" value="eijrgioerjboofphdpiappq" name="download">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

A file had been created but there was not any text.
I would like to send a pdf as base64 in a value... Maybe there is better way to do it? I know that this is a bit old technnology, but I thought it would be an easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that **urllib.parse.parse_qs(request_body)** returns empty dict...
I'm still trying to solve this problem but can't figure out why there's no value in **request_body**.